# Where does the common factor of a root go?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(3x-4)

Supposing this expression if a factor of some other expression,
We express the value of x on the number line as -4/3.

How does this take place? Do we take 3 as common? If yes, how is this 3 accounted for?

I know the question might sound very dumb but I genuinely need help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of $x$ would be $+\frac{4}{3}.$  You say that $(3x-4)$ is a factor of some expression.  If that expression is equal to zero, then one of the factors has to equal zero.  So one solution to the equation is $3x-4 = 0$.  Add $4$ to both sides to get $3x=4$.  Divide both sides by $3$ to get $x=\frac{4}{3}.$